# Grunt plugin: Cachebreaker "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Hey everybody I'm trying to add the "grunt-cache-breaker" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-breaker) to my gruntsetup. However this is the first plugin that I'm encountering issues with.

My build works just fine untill it tries to execute this part:

```
    cachebreaker: {
        addversions: {
            options: {
                match: ['*.{css,js}'],
                replacement: 'md5'
            },
            expand: true,
            cwd: '_output/',
            src: '*.html',
            dest: '_output/'
        },
    },
```

Then I get this part in my CMD

`Running "cachebreaker:addversions" (cachebreaker) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.`

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome! Thanks! :)

Comment: Looks like you need to add src: {path: '....'} inside your 'options' object, with path to your html/css sources. Did you try it?

Comment: That's exactly what the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This all feels very wrong, I'm looking for a generic solution that all .js files and all .css files that are included in all .html get a md5 hash at the end. How would I do this? This currently works but isnt what I was hoping for:

  cachebreaker: {
    options: {
     match:[{'init.js': '_output/_js/init.js','init.css':'_output/_css/init.css'}],
     replacement: 'md5'
    },
    files: {
     src: '_output/*.html'
    }
  },